# Modify JSON data after get in response

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs

I am getting JSON data. And I am using moment js for the time format. So I want to add some values after get the data. My data is like(0.0,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00 to 23.00). Right now I am getting some return values, Like 2.00, 3.00,4.00. My JSON data:

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "hr": 2,
        "minut": 2
    },
    "totoal": 42
},
{
    "_id": {
        "hr": 4,
        "minut": 3
    },
    "total": 144
},
{
    "_id": {
        "hr": 8,
        "minut": 5
    },
    "total": 188
},
{
    "_id": {
        "hr": 9,
        "minut": 10
    },
    "total": 128
}
]

var time =_.map(resp.data, function(res) { 
    return (res._id.hr + ':' + res._id.minut + 0)
});
```

When I print "time" in console then it is showing like this.

> 2:20,4:30,8:50,9:10

I want to set this timing for the graph. I can show you some snippet of graph for the more understanding.
[image]

But I want to modify these values Like

> 00:00, 1:00, 2:00, 3:00, 4:00, 5:00, 6:00, 7:00, 8:50, 9:00, 10:00,
>   11:50, 12.00, 13:10, 14:00, 15:00, 14:30,15:30

Desire Result:
[image]

SO right now I have getting  these **"2:20,4:30,8:50,9:10"** values in "time" variable with array form. So I want to show each hours in graph. But I am getting only some values not all(which time don't have data then it is not returning time slot). SO data is the total as shown in json data. But I want to show all time who has not data(total).

Comment: You probably need to loop through from 0 to your maximum time and create axis ticks in your graph code.  I doubt it has anything to do with your response data. What graphing library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [{
    "_id": {
      "hr": 2,
      "minut": 2
    },
    "totoal": 42
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "hr": 4,
      "minut": 3
    },
    "total": 144
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "hr": 8,
      "minut": 5
    },
    "total": 188
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "hr": 9,
      "minut": 10
    },
    "total": 128
  }
]

var time = [];

// you can replace  x with resp.data from your code
// this line  
// _.sortBy(x, function(res, idx) {
// will be
//_.sortBy(resp.data, function(res, idx) {


_.sortBy(x, function(res, idx) {
  if (typeof x[idx - 1] !== 'undefined') {
    if (((x[idx - 1])._id.hr + 1) !== res._id.hr) {
      for (var i = x[idx - 1]._id.hr + 1; i < res._id.hr; i++) {
        time.push(i + ':00');
      }
    }
  }
  time.push(('0' + res._id.hr).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + res._id.minut).slice(-2));
});

for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  var x = time[i - 1];
  if (x !== undefined) {
    var hr = parseInt(x, 10);
    if (hr > i) {
      time.splice(i - 1, 0, ('0' + i).slice(-2) + ':00');
    }
  } else {
    time.splice(i - 1, 0, ('0' + i).slice(-2) + ':00');
  }
}
console.log(time)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you want to add logic to start from 0:00 and end at 12:00 then you can modify logic little

Comment: I have tried this one. Can you attach some demo only for time values?

Comment: How to pass idx value. Because It is showing undefined.

Comment: you can check now, in console, it's working like charm.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Appreciate your effort. But when I am using this code then gives error, I cant understand.I an use your code with in  var time =_.map(resp.data, function(res) { 
    return (res._id.hr + ':' + res._id.minut + 0)
});.  What is the idx?

Comment: please check underscore syntax. ;-) or should i help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143975/discussion-between-v-sh-and-mehuljoshi).